# Saxon 9.9.1 to 12.3 upgrade is breaking sql:connect

Tags: saxon

I've been running sql connections successfully on 9.9.1.  I'm upgrading to 12.3, and am getting sql connection errors I can't figure out.  Looking at the documentation, the only difference I see from 9.9 to 12.3 is that specifying the driver in the connection is deprecated. (https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!changes/sql/9.9.1-12)

I run Saxon in a Jetty servlet.  `saxon-sql-12.3.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar` is in the classpath.

Connection is established with:

```
    <xsl:variable name="connection" select="sql:connect(map{'database':'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles','user':'username','password':'password','autoCommit':'1'}})"/>
```

Here is the error reported, with TIMING turned on.  Note it sometimes (not always) has the deprecation warning, yet I'm not specifying the driver in the `sql:connect()` map.

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for (unknown systemId) using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 0.060333ms
Tree size: 3 nodes, 0 characters, 0 attributes
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles")
   skipping: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   skipping: com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
   skipping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   skipping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   skipping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   skipping: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   trying com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
getConnection returning com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at net.sf.saxon.str.StringView.<init>(StringView.java:26)
    at net.sf.saxon.str.StringView.of(StringView.java:31)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue.<init>(StringValue.java:106)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue.<init>(StringValue.java:91)
    at com.saxonica.functions.sql.SQLFunctionSet.sqlQueryResult(SQLFunctionSet.java:64)
    at com.saxonica.functions.sql.SQLPreparedQueryFn.lambda$call$0(SQLPreparedQueryFn.java:67)
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.CallableFunction.call(CallableFunction.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.DynamicFunctionCall$DynamicFunctionCallElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPull$2(DynamicFunctionCall.java:356)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.MemoClosure.makeSequence(MemoClosure.java:94)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.MemoClosure.iterate(MemoClosure.java:85)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence.materialize(Sequence.java:61)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.elab.LocalVariableEvaluator.evaluate(LocalVariableEvaluator.java:31)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.elab.LearningEvaluator.evaluate(LearningEvaluator.java:61)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.UserFunctionCall.evaluateArguments(UserFunctionCall.java:616)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.UserFunctionCall$UserFunctionCallElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPull$0(UserFunctionCall.java:742)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.elab.PullElaborator.lambda$elaborateForBoolean$2(PullElaborator.java:65)
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.NotFn$NotFnElaborator.lambda$elaborateForBoolean$0(NotFn.java:129)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose$ChooseExprElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$10(Choose.java:1168)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block$BlockElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$1(Block.java:851)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression$LetExprElaborator.lambda$elaborateForPush$6(LetExpression.java:942)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:393)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.handleRuleNotNull(Mode.java:587)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:521)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.XsltController.applyTemplates(XsltController.java:684)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer.applyTemplates(Xslt30Transformer.java:438)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is Saxon bug 6159

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6159

which will be fixed in Saxon 12.4, currently in the final stages of testing.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I assumed it was me doing something wrong.  While we're waiting on 12.4, how far back do you think I should go to to avoid this bug so I can continue my development?  I'd like to get on 12.x to code so I can implement the better way to handle exceptions, but I can stay on 9.9.1 in the meantime if that is the last version without this bug.

Comment: The bug fix is present in 11.6, as indicated in the bug entry.

Comment: I see.  I didn't even think to look that 11.x would be updated before 12.x.  I assumed 12.x would always be the latest.  I read the description of the versions again, and I'm still not clear on which one is really the latest that I should be using.  I'll assume I should be using 11.x going forward and not 12.x.

Comment: We're currently producing maintenance releases on both the 11.x and 12.x branches, and by an accident of timing this patch hit the 11.x branch before it hit the 12.x branch. It could equally have been the other way around.